# Quantification of media interest in particular political subjects

Tags: statistics, media

I know there is a field of quantitative political science, but I am wondering if there are any commercial or quasi-commercial (amateur) efforts to just tally up how many articles or notices are published by the press on various political subjects.

For example, in the current US election, there has been huge media coverage of the Iowa caucuses, but a virtual media blackout on the New Hampshire primaries. Is there anybody out there actually counting up stories and numerically quantifying how many stories each news service does on various subjects (like election primaries)?

The reason I ask is that is so easy for someone to just say, "the media is ignoring this event", or over-covering this other event, but what actual hard scientific numbers do we have to objectively verify these kinds of statements?